# Why must a custom layout modifier be applied before a size modifier in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a custom modifier to centre a composable but I must call it before the `size` modifier else it has no effect. Why is it so?

```
fun Modifier.centre() = layout{ measurable, constraints ->
    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height){
        val x = constraints.maxWidth/2 - placeable.width/2
        val y = constraints.maxHeight/2 - placeable.height/2
        placeable.place(x = x, y = y )
    }

}

@Composable
fun ScreenSize(){
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(400.dp, 400.dp)
        .background(Color.Blue)){
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .centre()
            .size(200.dp, 300.dp)
            .background(Color.Yellow),){
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .centre()
                .size(120.dp, 150.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)
                ,){
                Text(text = "1", modifier = Modifier.centre(),
                    fontSize = 100.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
            }
        }
    }
}
```